# Momentjs what is wrong in my format

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Am I doing something wrong:

```
moment('Nov 29th 2012', 'MMM Do YYYY').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

I thought it should give `29/11/2012` but it gives `01/11/2012`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
moment('Nov 29th 2012', 'MMM DD YYYY').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

I'm not exactly sure why momentjs requires the extra `D`.

Comment: I guess it's a bug or the documentation is buggy, because there is no `DDo`.

Comment: @charles yeah I noticed that as well, the documentation is pretty lacking.

Comment: `Do` and `DDo` are not valid parsing tokens, but `DD` is. See all the parsing tokens here http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: My bad, there is a difference between here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ and here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ not really easy...

Comment: Yeah, there's no support for ordinal parsing as it doesn't add any more information than the number does, and there's no support for day of week and week of year as they don't really play well with other parsing tokens.